# Which life-cycle event should I execute my code in order for it to be after a Gridview is completely loaded?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, lifecycle

I have a quick question. I have a gridview that would generate a large result from a relatively long load time. I want to wait until the gridview is completely populated and loaded until I execute a certain code. Would I use this under Page_Load? I was looking at [these life-cycles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), and it looks like it could possibly fall into others as well, such as LoadComplete.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is related to processing the GridView after it's complete, then the most obvious event would be the [OnDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.ondatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Event Description

> This method notifies a server control that any data binding logic
>   associated with the control has completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly populating the GridView with a DataBind, then do it after you call the DataBind.

If the GridView is populated "automatically" with a datasourceid= in the aspx page, then you can do whatever in the page load event.